# How to get the list of files, that has been recently updated or modified using JPA Criteria Query?

Tags: java, subquery, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I am new to `JPA Criteria Query`.`Table` contains `meta-data` of the `files` and it may have multiple entries correspond to the`file name` but it should have different-different `last modified date` in the `Table`. What I need is - a list of `unique` files from the `Table` but that list should have all that files, that has been recently updated or modified.

Let's suppose I have a `Table` `ObjectMetadata` which has `file-name` and `last-modified`columns.

```
id, filename, lastmodified
01, A.txt,   25/10/2014
02, A.txt,   26/10/2014 
03, B.txt,   25/10/2014
04, B.txt,   27/10/2014 
05, C.txt,   25/10/2014
06, C.txt,   26/10/2014 
07, D.txt,   25/10/2014
08, D.txt,   27/10/2014
```

I need below result using `JPA Criteria Query`.  -

```
 id, filename, lastmodified
    02, A.txt,   26/10/2014 
    04, B.txt,   27/10/2014 
    06, C.txt,   26/10/2014 
    08, D.txt,   27/10/2014
```

SQL Query

```
SELECT filename, MAX(lastmodified) FROM objectmetadata GROUP BY filename;
```

Comment: You have not indicated what the problem is. Also note: JPA Criteria works with mapped domain entities, not tables. You have not shown any mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a mapping between your db table and JPA entity, something like this:

```
@Entity
public class ObjectMetadata {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String fileName;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastModified;

    // constructors, getters, setters
}
```

The query may then look as below:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<ObjectMetadata> root = cq.from(ObjectMetadata.class);
cq.multiselect(
    root.get("fileName").alias("filename"), 
    cb.greatest(root.<Date>get("lastModified").alias("lastmodified")
);
cq.groupBy(root.get("fileName"));

List<Tuple> result = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList()
for (Tuple t: result) {
    System.out.println(t.get("filename") + " " + t.get("lastmodified"));
}
```